# User Friendly Video Review with Locking

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session-timeout, onbeforeunload

We have a jquery/php/mysql system that allows a user to log in and review videos built by a system for online viewing.  When a user begins reviewing a video, the video is marked as such.  But now we've cornered ourselves into the classic browser-based application problem of the user navigating away or closing the browser without completing review.  That video would then enter a state of limbo of constantly being reviewed, but never completed, and never re-entering the queue.

Options we have are:

- Build a service (which we already have others) to find review sessions that are outside a duration boundary and reset them back into the queue.
- Reset review sessions outside a duration boundary when that user logs in.  Essentially, if a user locks out a video for review, it'll be unlocked the next time they log in.
- A suggestion made to me was to use the php/apache session length and on expiration, reset any pending review jobs.  I don't even know where to look to implement this as this is one project on a shared server, so it shouldn't be an apache config, but the reset mechanism would need to know the database credentials to be able to reset it...
- The worst solution everyone hates is preventing the user from navigating away with javascript, asking "Are you sure?!"

This system is used by a few hired reviewers, so I'm not exactly dealing with the public here, but I can't prevent users from sharing logins for speedier review, which would knock out the 2nd option above because it would unlock a video being reviewed by someone else using the same login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two good options that won't tax your server. Either:

1. Run a cron-job every hour looking for review sessions that are outside of the duration boundary.  This has the advantage of being transparent to the end user.  But it's possible to kill an active session if you're not careful (Suppose the user is operating in multiple tabs).
2. Prevent users from navigating away with JS.  Honestly, this is what I would do since the user is reviewing the video (if they were just viewing it, that would be bad, but since they know they are supposed to be acting, it's ok).  Just say *If you leave now, the review will be canceled, are you sure?*.

Honestly, I'd do option #2.  SO uses it, and it works well here.  It wouldn't be for every page, just those where there's an active review going on...

Comment: I'm using the PHP System_Daemon Pear Library that is working pretty well, rather than cron.  I was thinking of just making another daemon to perform a few maintenance things, having this service unlock sessions being one of them.

Comment: Ok, if you'd like, that would work.  I don't like keeping long-running PHP processes if I can help it (I've done it, but it can be a pita).  But if it's working for you, go for it...

Comment: The daemon's been running pretty well, it allows you to install a php script as a linux daemon.  I've been monitoring the memory usage and it's been pretty solid so far.

Answer (score 0):

When a single video is reviewed on a single page by one person. You can capture the JavaScript unload event which will be fired when the page unloads and the client is leaving the page. Than you can change the state of that video or even show a dialog and let the user decide.

Maybe a ping-pong system may help. In the back you make AJAX calls binded to a video by an ident. When that activity stops, the users stopped. A background process can look for latest ping and when that is, for instance, a hour ago, change it's state.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is your best bet. You can have a javascript timer on the page updating the lastestActivity record for the video while the browser window is open So you won't get into the corner of a review that takes too long and the unlocker releases the lock prematurely.

Option 2 is problematic for several reasons, some have already been mentioned but taking into account that a reviewer might not log in for a few days (vacation?) will unlock a video for too long unnecessarily.

Option 4 (Javascript onBeforeUnload) Won't cover you in the common cases of a browser crash, OS crash or a power failure. but it is something you can implement in addition.